# What is the functional way of printing items from range in one line?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(0,30,3):
    print(i)
```

What is the functional style of the imperative loop above?

```
lambda x: print(x), range(0,30,3)
```

Comment: found a duplicate myself

Comment: Well, you could choose to call it out and I'll close this question and delete my answer.

Comment: y = [i for i in range(0,30,3)]

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, no i want u to get 5 points for ur answer! ty

Comment: @inxoy Technically, `y = list(range(...))` works equally well and is more succinct.

Comment: _=[print(x) for x in range(30)]

Comment: @Silencer Just, no. Don't encourage the use of list comprehensions for side effects.

Comment: @ERJAN Very magnanimous of you, thanks ;-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Why? It's  just ok for me to quick print items.

Comment: @Silencer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thank you for correct me, I'll use it just for debuging ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `lambda` isn't necessary here. Just use the `*` unpacking operator.

```
In [163]: print(*range(0, 30, 3))
0 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27
```

If you want them printed in separate lines, that's doable too.

```
In [164]: print(*range(0, 30, 3), sep='\n')
0
3
6
9
12
15
18
21
24
27
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python 2.x you'll need future import:

```
from __future__ import print_function #dont't need this for python 3.x
print(*range(0,30,3), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

The functional way of doing things is *mapping collections to functions*

```
map(print, range(30))
```

However, because in python `map` returns a generator, you need to somehow iterate it, which you can do by converting it to a list

```
list(map(print, range(30)))
```

Comment: Realise that this is called "producing side effects" and generates a list of `[None, None, None, ...]`. This is generally discouraged and reduces readability.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Indeed. However, `print` inherently is used for its side effects. In a pure functional style, it wouldn't exist. In general however, given a pure function, this would be the way.

Comment: Yes, but you don't use `map` to exploit that?

Comment: I just wanted to give an example of mapping. Not saying it should be done this way. A simple for loop would be the clearest way in this case.